# Create generic Linq extension Method to "sew" data by Key

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have a collection of courses (Id, name, status, instructor, etc) and another collection of Pricing (CourseId, Price).

I am trying to write a linq extension method to merge these two together, but my reflection is a bit rusty. What am I missing?

**This is how I want to call it:**

```
courses.SewData(pricing, p => p.Id, c => c.CourseId);
```

This is the method that is being called. Im having issues with the ToDictionary Line. Its not compiling. How can I create a dictionary with my existing expression

```
public static class DataExtension {
    public static IEnumerable<TParent> SewData<TParent, TChild>(this IList<TParent> parentCollection, IList<TChild> childCollection, Expression<Func<TParent, object>> parentProperty, Expression<Func<TChild, object>> childProperty) {

        var parentPropertyInfo = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty(parentProperty);
        var childPropertyInfo = ReflectionHelper.GetProperty(childProperty);

        var parentDict = parentCollection.ToDictionary(parentProperty, x => x); //need help here
        foreach (var child in childCollection) {
            var childId = childPropertyInfo.GetValue(child);
            var parentItem = parentDict[childId];
            
            //use reflection here to map properties by name
            

            
            yield return parentItem;
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the inputs and Outputs you are trying to achieve? I think there's a simple solution here but it's hard to tell exactly from your description and the code what it is you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you don't need expressions and reflection for this part, you can try something like this (also added `TKey` generic parameter for key type):

```
public static class DataExtension {
    public static IEnumerable<TParent> SewData<TParent, TChild, TKey>(
         this IList<TParent> parentCollection, 
         IList<TChild> childCollection, 
         Func<TParent, TKey> parentKeySelector, 
         Func<TChild, TKey> childKeySelector) {

        var parentDict = parentCollection.ToDictionary(parentKeySelector); 
        foreach (var child in childCollection) {
            var childId = childKeySelector(child);
            var parentItem = parentDict[childId];
            
            //use reflection here to map properties by name             
              
            yield return parentItem;
        }          
    }
}
```

if you still need expressions later for some other reason you can use `Compile` to get `parentKeySelector` from `parentProperty`.

Comment: @ChrisKooken was glad to help!